# Could not resolve all files for configuration gradle build

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

I want tagsoup jar as dependency for one of my test case which reads a html.

In my build.gradle I have done these changes

```
asciidoctorj {
    version = '1.5.4'
}

repositories {
   maven {
      url "http://mvn-nexus.my.company:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/"
   }
   mavenCentral()
}
compile(
  'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.14',
  'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7',
  'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2',
  'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2',
  'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2',
  'ant:ant:1.7.0',
  'com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.19',
  'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1'
 )

testCompile(
  'junit:junit:4.12',
  'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.14',
  'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4',
  'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.12.0',
  'com.athaydes:spock-reports:1.4.0',
  'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13',
  'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.13',
  'com.lesfurets:jenkins-pipeline-unit:1.0',
  'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:1.2.1'
 )

varsCompile sourceSets.main.output

}
```

But I get the following error in my jenkins build while building this project

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:0.9.7:.
  >   Required by:
  >     project :

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the artefact name. Try :

```
'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1'
```